# Syntax error for SQL update statement in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I ran a SQL `UPDATE` statement in MS Access, but received a error message

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

I searched in internet, but any solutions works in my situation.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Command111_Click()
     CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE test3 " & _
                       "SET OrderStatus= 'Producing' " & _
                       "WHERE OrderID='" & Me!cboOrderID1 & "' ProductName='" & Me!ComboProduct1 & "'"
End Sub
```

Please help me check where is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure there should be an `AND` between the two conditions you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys! This code works in my situation.

Private Sub Command111_Click()

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE test3 " & _
"SET OrderStatus= 'Producing' " & _
"WHERE OrderID='" & Me!cboOrderID1 & "' AND ProductName=" &CStr(Me!ComboProduct1) & ""
End Sub
```

In my case, the ProductName is sourced from a combo box.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that OrderID is int so it cannot be in `''` quotes and must be as number in statement

```
"WHERE OrderID=" & Me!cboOrderID1 & " AND/OR ProductName='" & Me!ComboProduct1 & "'"
```

Also you forgot to use AND or OR

Answer (score 1):

Forgot your AND

```
 Private Sub Command111_Click()

    CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE test3 " & _
    "SET OrderStatus= 'Producing' " & _
    "WHERE OrderID='" & Me!cboOrderID1 & "' AND ProductName='" & Me!ComboProduct1 & "'"
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much Justin for your quick response. the code now looks good but I received a mistype error. what I did is to update OrderStatus in a table based on a form input. In the table, OrderID is a string, ProductName is numeric looking up reference, OrderStatus is a string. In the form, OrderID is combo box sourced from the table, ProductName in the form is a combo box originated from the same source as the ProductName in table. if I do an append , those data seems good without any mistype error. could you kindly help me analyze where is the mistype source.

Comment: did you try cboOrderID1.Text, and ComboProduct1.Value? Are you sure that OrderID is a string? It would make sense to me that OrderID would be a numeric value, and ProductName would be the string. If that is the case you would want your WHERE to be: `Where OrderID='" & cboOrderID1.value & "' AND ProductName='" & ComboProduct1.Text & "'"`